How to make a Installable Sage Wordpress Theme?
I am building my own theme using the Sage WordPress theme template. I can build the development version of my theme, but I am unsure how to compress it into a usable .zip file for production.
I tried using a theme download plugin, but the resulting zip file was around 70MB because it included the node_modules folder.
Here is a section of my package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "bud dev",
    "build": "bud build",
    "translate": "npm run translate:pot && npm run translate:update",
    "translate:pot": "wp i18n make-pot . ./resources/lang/sage.pot --include=\"theme.json,patterns,app,resources\"",
    "translate:update": "for file in ./resources/lang/*.po; do wp i18n update-po ./resources/lang/sage.pot $file; done",
    "translate:compile": "npm run translate:mo && npm run translate:js",
    "translate:js": "wp i18n make-json ./resources/lang --pretty-print",
    "translate:mo": "wp i18n make-mo ./resources/lang ./resources/lang"
  },

I know there is a build command in package.json which creates a /public directory, but my question is: What exactly do I need to compress into a zip file for it to be a usable theme?
Here's what my project directory looks like:

Same question asked here

It depends on what hosting your going to use , if your using shared hosting you would need dist and vendor folders uploaded to  the server using ftp , because mostly there is no CI/CD , while on other hosting options like a VPS there is one so you dont have to upload the dist and vendor folders, if you dont mind me asking sage 9 or 10 ? and are you using bedrock or just the wordpress environment?
